# In yaml-cpp, can the node tags be used to store custom data?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm thinking of assigning my own unique id string to each `YAML::Node` via the `SetTag()` function. Is this possible, or is `yaml-cpp` referencing these tags internally, and it'll get confused?
Also, is this likely to be a problem in future versions of the library?

Comment: This is the intended use of tags in yaml AFAIK and I use yaml-cpp with `SetTag()` for exactly this purpose. Note however, that I also had a few issues with the tag support in yaml-cpp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502063/yaml-cpp-doesnt-roundtrip-with-local-tags

Comment: More precisely, I use the tags to tell my code about the type that the yaml node shall be deserialized to. I just realized this is not entirely what you want to do, right? So maybe your use case is not the intended use for yaml tags, but I suppose you could still use them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible!The yaml-cpp tags are intended for this purpose.**

> Also, is this likely to be a problem in future versions of the
> library?

It should not create problem in the future version of the library, but for safety you can ask a question to the mantainer on the github [repo](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) of the library opening an issue or a discussion if possible.